# Getting multiple values from same column seperated by "/" in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, select, tableau-api

I have a table in an excel sheet and I am using Custom SQL option in Tableau. The table has the below structure:

---

```
     Project        Identified          Led     Fee

     1          Employee1           Employee2   100000
     2          Employee2           Employee3   200000
     3      Employee1 / Employee2   Employee1   300000
```

I am using the below code to obtain the  next structure:

```
select [Identified] as Name, [Project], 'Identified' as Contribution, [Fee]
union
select [Led], [Project], 'Led', [Fee]
```

---

```
     Name       Project     Contribution        Fee

     Employee1      1       Identified      100000
     Employee1      3       Identified      300000
     Employee1      3       Led             300000
     Employee2      1       Led             100000
     Employee2      2       Identified      200000
     Employee2      3       Identified      300000
     Employee3      2       Led             200000
```

But of course I cannot separate "Employee1 / Employee2" as above. 
How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to select "Employee1" you cou use a WHERE. 
For example:

TableA:

```
(Column: Name) - (Column: Colour)
Employee1 - Purple 
Employee1 - Blue 
Employee2 - White
```

Code:

```
SELECT Name, Colour 
FROM TableA 
WHERE Name = 'Employee1'
```

Comment: I have more than 300 employees, and it can be any combination of those, and I want to be able to extract both of them and generate 2 different rows in the new table.

Comment: Maybe you could use: WHERE Name LIKE '%Employee1%' Then you can also fetch those colums.Then you can make a loop that looks if 'Name' has a 'slach'. If yes, take a part of the old value. And take the new value as a replacement of the old value.

Comment: Maybe this is nice as well: [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php) You can put the SELECT.... in a Cursus and then go through every value.

Answer (score 0):

You have a many-to-many relationship named "Identified" between Project and Employee. Representing one-to-many relationships by cramming multiple values into a single field with some sort of separator leads to all kinds of difficulties, which is why relational database design strongly discourages that approach and encourages factoring repeating information into a new table (or worksheet in the Excel case).

So a more flexible approach is to have a worksheet for Employees with one employee per row and have an employee id column to uniquely identify each employee. It can be a synthesized internal-only id. Have a similar worksheet for Projects. And finally a third linking or join table worksheet to represent the Identified association -- with two columns an employee id and a project id. Each row in that table indicates that a particular employee helped identify a particular project.

If a project can have multiple leaders, you can use the same approach for that association. If not, you can just have a leader_id column in the Project table. If you factor out the association, you can add information tied to the association such as dates, roles etc, but that can add some complexity.

This is standard database design. Well understood for going on 40 years. See any book on database design or data modeling for information on database normalization for more info. Your design violates first normal form, and its usually a good idea to strive for at least third normal form -- and then back off in special cases for performance optimization or read-only warehouse designs.

You can stick with your current design, and try to hack something into each application that reads the data to try to handle the separators to deal with multi-valued fields. But you'll be fighting your data instead of organizing it in a way that represents the relationships naturally.